# How To Search And Replace Across Multiple Files In Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a folder with a few hundred-word documents. I want to be able to replace the words `ORG NAME` by clicking a macro, filling in an input box and letting it iterate. There are thousands of instances of `ORG NAME` across these documents and this process needs to happen a few dozen times a year.

We've got some challenges with trust centre policies in place that can't be changed so the macro needs to be done via excel.

The below was sort of working as word macro although it was crashing a lot, I moved it over to excel and now I'm getting the error: `Named argument not found` against `macroname:`

I can't find any similar questions that aren't solved by correcting spelling.

I'm also open to *better* solutions if they exist, this has been my first attempt so far.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 300) As String '300 files is the maximum applying this code
Dim xFindStr As String
Dim xReplaceStr As String
Dim xDoc As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With xFileDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.docx", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    i = 1
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
            i = i + 1
        Next
        i = i - 1
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFindStr = "ORG NAME"
    xReplaceStr = InputBox("Enter the name of the organisation:", "Document Updater for Word", xReplaceStr)
    For j = 1 To i Step 1
        Set xDoc = Documents.Open(Filename:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
        Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = xFindStr  'Find What
            .Replacement.Text = xReplaceStr  'Replace With
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchByte = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Application.Run macroname:="NEWMACROS"
        ActiveDocument.Save
        ActiveWindow.Close
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
MsgBox "Operation end, please view", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: If all the files are in a single directory then all you need to do is select the directory and then iterate the files and searching only those which are word documents.  I'd use the Scripting.FileSystemObject if you can to iterate the files in a directory.  Also, you don't mention if you have added the Word Object model in the Tools.references dialog.  You can't use the Excel search function to search in a word document

Comment: You’ve moved the code to Excel so `Application` now refers to Excel, not Word.

Comment: You’ll also need an object variable that points to the Word application. You’ll find lots of examples on SO of working with Word from Excel.

Comment: If you develop a method, please do post it here as an answer. If you still need help, instead, post what you develop and someone will help with it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A few links on SO showed that I didn't need to use the work object reference model if I didn't use any variables from it, `Dim xDoc As Object` was `Dim xDoc As Document` which was the only reference to word explicitly I think.

Comment: If this code is running in Excel then e.g. `Selection` refers to the selection within Excel. But if you want it to reference the active Word-Selection then you definitly have to name that explicitly as `Word.Selection` - therefore you need a reference to the Word-object-model

Answer (score 0):

See this page by Ibby on the Word MVP website.

### [How to Find & ReplaceAll on a batch of documents in the same folder](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/BatchFR.htm)

> The following code, if stored in a Global template, will perform a
> Find & ReplaceAll in all of the documents in a specified folder. The
> FindReplace dialog is displayed for the first document only. The user
> sets the parameters in the dialog and presses Replace All and then
> Close. The user is then asked whether to process all of the files in
> the specified directory – if Yes, the rest of the files are processed
> with the settings as entered in the original FindReplace dialog.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BatchReplaceAll()

Dim FirstLoop As Boolean
Dim myFile As String
Dim PathToUse As String
Dim myDoc As Document
Dim Response As Long

PathToUse = "C:\Test\"

'Error handler to handle error generated whenever
'the FindReplace dialog is closed

On Error Resume Next

'Close all open documents before beginning

Documents.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges

'Boolean expression to test whether first loop
'This is used so that the FindReplace dialog will
'only be displayed for the first document

FirstLoop = True

'Set the directory and type of file to batch process

myFile = Dir$(PathToUse & "*.doc")

While myFile <> ""

    'Open document
    Set myDoc = Documents.Open(PathToUse & myFile)

    If FirstLoop Then

        'Display dialog on first loop only

        Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show

        FirstLoop = False

        Response = MsgBox("Do you want to process " & _
        "the rest of the files in this folder", vbYesNo)
        If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Else

        'On subsequent loops (files), a ReplaceAll is
        'executed with the original settings and without
        'displaying the dialog box again

        With Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
            .ReplaceAll = 1
            .Execute
        End With

    End If

    'Close the modified document after saving changes

    myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges

    'Next file in folder

    myFile = Dir$()

Wend

End Sub
```

That should get you started. The page has more on subfolders and password protected files.

If you need to do more than find and replace, see also utilities for batch processing documents by [Greg Maxey](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/process_batch_folder_addin.html) and by [Graham Mayor](http://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm).

Comment: these look perfect the batch processing utilities. Do you know if they work with office 16?

Comment: They work with Office 2016 (and 2019, 2021)